# Azure DevOps Dashboards - Burndown chart

Tags: azure, azure-devops, dashboard

I have created 3 new sprints and Future dated them. I working on creating dashboards for each of the sprints. When I add a Burndown chart I can only select current or pass Iterations but not any futures sprints . why ? is there a setting to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, I can reproduce the same situation when using **Sprint BurnDown** Chart.

The sprint burndown widget will display the current iteration (date) and the previous iteration. Future iterations will not appear in the widget until the start date is reached.

This is expected behavior and I am afraid that there is no method to avoid it.

For a workaround, you can change to use another chart: Burndown chart.

[image]

It supports custom time interval.

For example:

[image]